# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project to upload images from the gallery to firebase storage. I am facing the error that the User is not authorized to perform the desired action, but I am able to perform all other actions, e.g making a collection for users on firestore, etc, but I can't upload images to firebase storage.

Images are attached below.

My code for uploading images to firebase storage/firestore: [Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBlsW.png)

The rule I am using: [Firebase Storage Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYg0n.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules you've attached in the screenshot are of Cloud Firestore. Firebase storage has its own security rules.
Please make sure you've created a bucket in Firebase Storage from the console and set the rules that allow the relevant users to upload

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

These rules will allow authenticated users upload and download files. Please let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It worked !

Comment: @Dharmaraj you saved me